# CUPS client not working with docker container name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cups

CUPS client cannot print when providing the CUPS server as container name, while it works fine with the container IP:

Sample `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  client:
    container_name: cups_client
    image: cups_client

  server:
    container_name: cups_server
    image: cups_server
```

The client container's `/etc/cups/client.conf` uses the name of the server container:

```
ServerName cups_server
```

However, this configuration does not work properly (run inside client container):

```
$ lpstat -r
scheduler is running
$ lpstat -v
lpstat: Error - add '/version=1.1' to server name.
```

I tried to add '/version=1.1' to the server name in `/etc/cups/client.conf`, but the error still shows.

However, if I use the server *container's IP address* in `/etc/cups/client.conf`, printing works just fine:

```
ServerName 172.27.0.2
```

See difference in `lpstat -v`:

```
$ lpstat -r
scheduler is running
$ lpstat -v
device for queue_name: ipp://192.168.0.10/ipp/port1
```

Name resolution seems to work fine in the client container however:

```
$ getent hosts cups_server
172.27.0.2      cups_server
```

Now using the IP is not really an option, as the printing configuration is provided during build time already, when the IP is not yet known. Also in my understanding CUPS should work just fine with the container name.

Grateful for any idea how to solve this, or why cups would not get along with the container name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a CUPS server config issue.

CUPS server logs in `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
Request from "172.27.0.3" using invalid Host: field "cups-server:631".
```

Solution:

Add `ServerAlias cups-server` in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`